# A spring-cloud-releasetrain like spring-data?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I saw a blog entry ([Spring Cloud service release: Angel.SR3](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/26/spring-cloud-service-release-angel-sr3)) almost two months ago about how Spring Cloud will be organized using release trains.  I am a big fan of this as it make it easier for developers to determine what versions of various libraries play well together.

With that in mind, this is exactly what the Spring Platform BOM was created for.  As far as I can tell, the Spring Cloud release train hasn't yet been included in the platform BOM yet (not to be confused with spring-cloud-connectors).  Will this be something that gets added soon or is there a reason to manage it separately?

-Joshua

Sample projects:

**SPRING PLATFORM**

```
io.spring.platform:platform-bom:1.1.3.RELEASE 
-parent-> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:1.2.5.RELEASE
-parent-> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.2.5.RELEASE
```

**SPRING BOOT**

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:1.2.5.RELEASE
-parent-> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.2.5.RELEASE
```

**SPRING DATA MONGDB**

Note: Folded into Spring Platform via -> org.springframework.data:spring-data-releasetrain:Evans-SR3

```
org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:1.7.2.RELEASE
-parent-> org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb-parent:1.7.2.RELEASE
-parent-> org.springframework.data.build:spring-data-parent:1.6.2.RELEASE
-parent-> org.springframework.data.build:spring-data-build:1.6.2.RELEASE
```

**SPRING CLOUD**

Note: org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-parent:Angel.SR3 is the release train coordinator, but is not yet included in the spring platform BOM

```
org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-parent:Angel.SR3
-parent-> org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-parent:1.0.2.RELEASE
-parent-> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:1.2.4.RELEASE
-parent-> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.2.4.RELEASE
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data manages its own release train even if it does get included in the Spring IO Platform.  Spring Cloud will always manage its own release train.  It will move faster than the Spring IO Platform.  You could [submit an issue](https://github.com/spring-io/platform/issues) to have Spring Cloud included in the Spring Platform.

Comment: Punchline: won't fix (closed).  So if you write reusable spring components at a company, you'll need to have your components point to cloud for dependency management because that drives the version of the platform that gets used (not the other way around). This works differently than I thought as this is the only other spring project that works this way.  Cloud drives the version of platform (the entire spring ecosystem), not the other way around.

Comment: We originally aligned our reusable components with a version of the platform thinking that this was the best way of aligning dependencies trying to ensure that everything plays nice together.  As we experienced on a recent project, this becomes problematic when cloud depends on an older version of platform than our common components.  Then you have maven trying to rationalize dependency versions across two different versions of platform, choosing the newest version.  I thought that this was exactly the issue that platform was looking to solve.